# What is the meaning of "He did not have that gift with her"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of "He did not have that gift with her" in [the following paragraph](http://readtheory.org/advanced/Remains_of_a_Marriage.htm)?

> No, Kelsey did not "remember the culture." She could care less about the culture. However, Robert, the history professor, was obviously enthralled by the contractor's findings. He had an innate way of understanding other cultures and other people that amazed Kelsey. **He did not have that gift with her**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means that Robert didn't have the ability to understand his wife so well as he did other cultures and other people. As this story is told from Kelsey's viewpoint, it is probably an expression of complaint that her husband doesn't understand her as much as she would like him to.